# $\mathcal{O}_K/\lambda^2\simeq \mathbb{Z}/q^2\mathbb{Z}$ for $\lambda$ a prime ideal where $K=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-d}]$

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-d}]$ be a quadratic imaginary field with ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$. Let $\lambda$ be a prime ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$ with $N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(\lambda)=q$. Since $\mathcal{O}_K/\lambda$ is a finite integral domain, it is a field, and with a little thought one can check that it has characteristic $q$. Additionally it has (basically by definition of the norm) $q$ elements. Thus $\mathcal{O}_K/\lambda\simeq \mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$ as fields.

**Question**: When we consider the square of the prime ideal, $\lambda^2$, we can see that $\mathcal{O}_K/\lambda^2$ has $q^2$ elements, characteristic $q$, and precisely one proper ideal: $\lambda$. Is this enough to conclude that $\mathcal{O}_K/\lambda^2\simeq \mathbb{Z}/q^2\mathbb{Z}$ as rings? What is this isomorphism map explicitly? Can we generalize this to show $\mathcal{O}_K/\lambda^n\simeq \mathbb{Z}/q^n\mathbb{Z}$ as rings?

Comment: $O_K/\lambda^2$ has characteristic $q^2$ iff $\lambda$ is unramified (ie. $q\not \in \lambda^2$) otherwise it has characteristic $q$ and it is isomorphic to $\Bbb{F}_q[x]/(x^2)$ not $\Bbb{Z}/(q^2)$. If unramified then (assuming $q\ne 2$) the isomorphism $O_K/\lambda^n\to \Bbb{Z}/(q^n)$ is sending $\sqrt{-d}$ to a root of $x^2+d\bmod q^n$.

Comment: You obviously need $q$ to be prime for your reasoning to work; regardless: yes when $\lambda$ is umramified, ie $q \notin \lambda^2$ (that is, we have: $O_K/\lambda^n \cong \mathbb{Z}/q^n\mathbb{Z}$). The idea is that replacing $O_K$ with $R=(O_K)_{\lambda}$ doesn’t change anything; but $R$ is a DVR with uniformizer $q$ and residue field generated by $\mathbb{Z}$, and the rest is formal.